# Add hidden value to imput form (probably JS)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So, I have this html form which the user fills up with his/her info. There is the mobile number field.

I´d like to add the country code automatically, but **hidden** from the user (since it´s going to be just a local - geographic - marketing action, it´s a fixed code), so I can receive the mobile number with the country code added directly to the database.

All I need is that the form (or JS) adds the value "11" to the beginning of the mobile number without the user noticing it. The user writes "321-456789" and I will receive "**11**321456789".

How to code that?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please update your question and provide a MRE (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
with relevant code parts.

Comment: is it always `11`? if so why don't you just add that serverside when you receive the request?

Comment: @Spectric Well. He's asking a specific question with numbers and he already "have this html form in which the user .."  Then he goes on and describe what the form does. I don't see why it would not be a great addition to have some or all of the code?

Comment: @Spectric, it[s a regular form code:
    <label for="mobile">
                <input id="mobile" name="MOBILE_NUMBER_" type="tel" required placeholder="mobile">
              </label>

Comment: Let's agree to disagree.

Comment: @Spectric, Im thinking the theory here. I should probably write a JS that would add the value "11" but hidden from the user, so it would be something like get element by id > add value "11", but how to make it invisible for the user?

Comment: @Spectric, yeah, I was thinking something like that (button thing), I just would like to know how to do that (since Im junior on JS)
But alright then, you alread helped me , I can go now and look for how to code that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JS to prepend (kudos to Stephen P's amazing vocabulary) "11" to the value of the input field like so:

```js
function append11(){
    var mobilenumber = document.getElementById("phonenumber");
  var front = document.getElementById("front").value;
  mobilenumber.value=front+mobilenumber.value;

}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="phonenumber"><input type="number" value="11" id="front" hidden><button onclick="append11()">
Append 11
</button>
```

In the example above, whatever you input, after clicking the 'Append 11' button, will add "11" to the front of the value. You can configure this to submit a form like so:

```js
function append11(){
    var mobilenumber = document.getElementById("phonenumber");
  var front = document.getElementById("front").value;
  mobilenumber.value=front+mobilenumber.value;
  alert(mobilevalue.value);

}
```

```html
<form action="something" method="GET">
<input name="phonenumber" type="number" id="phonenumber"><input type="number" value="11" id="front" hidden><button onclick="append11()">
Submit
</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Just to be pedantic -- the word "append" means to add _at the **end**_, one cannot "append to the front" — if you are adding at the _start_, like the question wants, the word for that is _**prepend**_.

Comment: @StephenP Sorry.

Comment:   no need for sorry, just trying to be informative

Comment: @Spectric, it worked indeed. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @StephenP, thanks for the info too. I had no idea about that