# How can my user hit enter or click a button to submit and be redirected?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this html form:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Equation" id="equation_input" onsubmit="return button_click()"/>
    <input class = "search_button" type="submit" id="search" onclick="button_click()" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

And I need to take the value the user entered in the equation input, add it to the beginning of a url, and then redirect the user to that newly formed url.
I tried this in my script tags:

```
function button_click() {
    var url = `https://exampleurl.com?q=${document.getElementById('equation_input').value}`;
    window.location.replace(url);
}
```

I've tried a couple things, but I'm not sure what's causing the problem so I don't know exactly what to try.

Comment: whats the problem ?

Comment: I don't know. But my buttons just reload the page instead of redirecting the user. Idk what part is causing it though.

Comment: That's because you aren't preventing the default form submit.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense that you need to when you can use default submit instead. Do some research into `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 4):

No need for any js to do this. It can be done by default form submit by naming the input and setting action and method attributes of the form.

Note that an `<input>` has no `submit` event, only a `<form>` does

```
<form method="GET" action="https://exampleurl.com">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Equation" id="equation_input" name="q" required/>
  <input class="search_button" type="submit" id="search" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Using an input as a submission method is never the best solution. `<button>` will do just fine.

Comment: @Spectric Provide a citation for that claim.  `<input type="submit"/>` has been used since inception of forms. I personally use button but both are valid

Comment: Using `<input>` is redundant as you need to add `type="submit"`. `<button>` is automatically set to submit when it is clicked. Also, if you personally use button, then why are you encouraging the use of input?

Comment: @Spectric Fine but that is simply personal preference

Comment: You are completely right. I'm just picky sometimes ;)

Comment: I need js so I can add their input to my default url. Is there any way to do that within html?

Comment: @Kai I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64234695/add-hidden-value-to-imput-form-probably-js/64235008#64235008) will solve the problem in that case.

Comment: Use `<input type="hidden" name="typeNameHere" value="putValueHere"/>`

Comment: @Kai What do you mean by *"add to defualt url"*? You can easily modify the `action` url in a submit event handler if needed

Comment: what's a submit event handler?

Comment: Do a search for *"javascript form submit handler"*. Suggest you study some tutorials on using javascript with forms